# Getting error while running SAS code

Tags: sas, datastep

I'm getting an error while running the below code. `&CNT` is `50` and `&vars` has column names in it.

Each column as some values from `1` to `100`. I want to select each column and check the below criteria (`%if` statement), creating a new variable and assigning the values to it (like `free`, `partially free` and `not free`).

```
option mlogic mprint;
%macro analysis();
DATA Q2;
SET Q1;
%do i=1 %to &CNT.;
%let segs =%scan(&VARS.,&i.," ");
%IF &SEGS.<=2.5 %THEN &SEGS._R="FREE";
%ELSE %IF (&SEGS.>2.5 AND &SEGS.<5.5) %THEN &SEGS._R="PARTLY FREE";
%ELSE %IF &SEGS.>=5.5 %THEN &SEGS._R="NOT FREE";
/*%PUT &segs.;*/
%end;
RUN;
%MEND;
%analysis();
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
SAS LOG ERROR:

MPRINT(ANALYSIS):   DATA Q2;
MPRINT(ANALYSIS):   SET Q1;
MLOGIC(ANALYSIS):  %DO loop beginning; index variable I; start value is 1;     stop value is 56; by value
  is 1.
MLOGIC(ANALYSIS):  %LET (variable name is SEGS)
MLOGIC(ANALYSIS):  %IF condition &SEGS.<=2.5 is FALSE
MLOGIC(ANALYSIS):  %IF condition (&SEGS.>2.5 AND &SEGS.<5.5) is FALSE
MLOGIC(ANALYSIS):  %IF condition &SEGS.>=5.5 is TRUE
MLOGIC(ANALYSIS):  %PUT &segs.
yr1960
MLOGIC(ANALYSIS):  %DO loop index variable I is now 2; loop will iterate again.
MLOGIC(ANALYSIS):  %LET (variable name is SEGS)
MLOGIC(ANALYSIS):  %IF condition &SEGS.<=2.5 is FALSE
MLOGIC(ANALYSIS):  %IF condition (&SEGS.>2.5 AND &SEGS.<5.5) is FALSE
MLOGIC(ANALYSIS):  %IF condition &SEGS.>=5.5 is TRUE
***NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "SEGS".
1      yr1961_R
   --------
   22
```

Comment: Why are you using macro logic inside a data step? You can't compare macro variables to floating point numbers without using %sysevalf.  At any rate, I don't think you need the macro loop, try rewriting without macro logic and see if that works for you?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing IF conditions inside the Macro processor versus inside the Data Step.  I think this is what you want.

```
%macro analysis();
DATA Q2;
SET Q1;
%do i=1 %to &CNT.;
%let segs =%scan(&VARS.,&i.," ");
IF &SEGS.<=2.5 THEN &SEGS._R="FREE";
ELSE IF (&SEGS.>2.5 AND &SEGS.<5.5) THEN &SEGS._R="PARTLY FREE";
ELSE IF &SEGS.>=5.5 THEN &SEGS._R="NOT FREE";
/*%PUT &segs.;*/
%end;
RUN;
%MEND;
%analysis();
```

Macros write code for you.  You were comparing the variable Name to the constant values (using string ordering, no less), not the variable values versus the constant values using numbers.